# Onscreen Confirmation Before Submit? PHP/SQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, forms

I currently have quite a basic HTML form that uses a PHP page to submit data to a simple database.

I'm wondering if it's possible to have all of the submitted data below the form before it gets sent to the database for the user to confirm it's correct.
Also wondering if theres a way for the user to submit several forms from the same page at the same time?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: _"Also wondering if theres a way for the user to submit several forms from the same page at the same time?"_ you might be able to make something with AJAX, but this just sounds like poor UI design.

Comment: Yes, its possible, but have you tried it? Nobody will write you here whole code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I have understood it, but you might get something done using javascript. You make a function which will be triggered when pressing the submit button. This submit button, must be a normal button to do this. Then you use an onclick event to trigger the function. Something like this.

```
<form id="FormId" action="Page.php" method="POST"><!--you can use any method you want here, I used POST-->
    <!--Here are some input fields-->
    <input type="Button" id="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="MyFunction()"/>
</form>
```

in your javascript(seperate file or inside the documents head tags), you put this function:

```
function MyFunction(){
    var data1 = document.getElementById('inputID').value;
    var data2 = document.getElementById('2einputID').value;
        //You place the data where you want it, like this:
    document.getElementById('IDDestination').value = data1;
        //You could submit the file like this:
    document.getElementById('FormId').submit();
        //You could make a confirm popup to make sure all is OK:
    var proceed = confirm("Submit Data? Data1="+data1+" and Data2="+data2);
    if(proceed){
        document.getElementById('FormId').submit();
    }
}
```

I hope this helpes.